# Switch monitors in xorg.conf in a dual screen setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, xorg.conf

I want to set up a dual screen config, so two completely separate :0.0 and :0.1 screens that have nothing to do with each other. The following configuration works except that screen :0.0 is displayed on the VGA output (which weirdly is called DP-1) but I would want it to be on :0.1 and :0.0 should be the HDMI-1 output:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "DP-1"
    Option         "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "HDMI-1"
    Option         "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
    Screen          0
    Driver         "modesetting"
    Option         "Monitor-HDMI-1" "HDMI-1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
    Screen          1
    Driver         "modesetting"
    Option         "Monitor-DP-1" "DP-1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "HDMI-1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "DP-1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

No matter how I name anything xorg keeps assigning the VGA output to screen :0.0 and I can see the following lines in the Xorg.0.log:

```
[     5.314] (WW) modeset(0): Option "Monitor-HDMI-1" is not used
[     5.412] (WW) modeset(1): Option "Monitor-DP-1" is not used
```

I did not post the whole log because it's 902 lines long but I can cut&paste anything from it if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via the nvidia driver with the metamodes option

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "HDMI-1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "DP-1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

There may be something similar for the modesetting driver you're using.

It looks like there is a `ZaphodHeads` option that you could try out.
From: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/xserver-xorg-core/modesetting.4.en.html

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "HDMI-1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "ZaphodHeads" "HDMI-1"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "DP-1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "ZaphodHeads" "DP-1"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: `ZaphodHeads` works indeed!

Comment: Very cool, may I ask what desktop environment you're working in and if it works with the separate X screens properly?

Comment: It's a debian with XFCE and no, it doesn't work properly but I've switched the window manager to compiz-reloaded + emerald and I use cairo-dock to supplement XFCE's panel. Which was a lot of work to install and configure but I prefer seperate screens. Sometimes I still have startup errors but after that this system works perfectly.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the information. I'm currently trying to get a similar set up working on RHEL 8 and have been unsuccessful thus far. I will have to give it a shot using what you described. It's a shame that there's such a lack of support for this set up, I know it's not popular, but I've grown to really prefer to separate out the displays.

Answer (score 0):

## Xinerama

### (If i recall correctly) is desktop spanning.

**This is how you would make "2 monitors as 1 Monitor"**
remove  that option first and try.

beyond that: I believe the format is XServer # and Screen #
so Server 0 Screen 0 or 1
:0.0 :0.1
or is it a comma... ":0,0"

Comment: Like I said, this configuration works, Xinerama is disabled by that option. No need to shout.

Comment: Intended as a heading/title.